# Custom (localised) appendix numbering style

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

I am trying to write a XeLaTeX-based report with the following conditions:

- A section number should be using Arabic numbers (1, 2, 3, ...)
- An appendix section number should be  using Thai letters (ก, ข, ค, ...)

However, by using `polyglossia`, ones can determine the following `numeral` option for `setmainlanguage`:

- `\setmainlanguage[numerals=thai]{thai}`: The appendix number will be as desired, but the section number will be in Thai (๑, ๒, ๓, ...)
- `\setmainlanguage[numerals=arabic]{thai}`: The section number will be as desired, but the appendix number will be in English (A, B, C, ...)

Are there any ways to mix up these two numeral rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the command:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thaiAlph{section}}
```

after the `\appendix` command.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{thai}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Laksaman}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale “th_TH”

\begin{document}
\section{บทหนึ่ง}
\section{บทสอง}

\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thaiAlph{section}}
\section{ผนวกหนึ่ง}
\section{ผนวกสอง}
\end{document}
```

gives the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the page counter to use Thai digits.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{thai}
\newfontfamily\thaifont{THSarabunNew001.ttf}
\renewcommand\thepage{{\thaifont\thaidigits{\the\value{page}}}}
\begin{document}

\section{Hello World}

\end{document}
```