# Thai Alphabet page numbering

Tags: polyglossia

I don't know how to make Thai alphabet page numbering. I try

```
\renewcommand{page}{\thaialph{}}
```

but it doesn't work. Could you please help me with how to do it?

I'm using XelaTeX with the polyglossia package.

Thai Alphabet start with ก

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19228/250119 can help? // could it be you need the A to be capitalized? E.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495640/250119

Comment: I try with page number and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please post a full MWE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `\thaiAlph` and to fix the redefinition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\setmainlanguage{thai}
\setmainfont{Thonburi}
\newfontfamily{\thaifont}{Thonburi}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thaiAlph{page}}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcounter{test}
\renewcommand{\thetest}{\thaiAlph{test}}
\prg_replicate:nn { 20 } { \stepcounter{test}\thetest\space }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\mbox{}\clearpage
\mbox{}\clearpage
\mbox{}\clearpage
\mbox{}\clearpage
\mbox{}\clearpage
\mbox{}\clearpage

\end{document}
```

I set up a counter to print the first twenty letters in `\thaiAlph`. Note that `geometry` is only used to make a smaller picture.

There are two font declarations because Thonburi seems not to advertise it supports Thai. Depending on your font, you may be able to use just `\setmainfont`.

[image]